# Is type checking for references in a template class less strict?

Tags: c++, templates, types, reference

The following is allowd in C++ through promotion:

```
int ivalue = true;
bool bvalue = 1;
```

Thats okay. And this is not allowed, through type-checking:

```
int& ivalue = false;
bool& bvalue = 0;
```

Thats okay.

Look on this, from Wikipedia.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Property_(programming)#C.2B.2B

```
#include <iostream>

template <typename T> class property {
        T value;
    public:
        T & operator = (const T &i) {
            ::std::cout << "T1: " << i << ::std::endl;
            return value = i;
        }
        // This template class member function template serves the purpose to make
        // typing more strict. Assignment to this is only possible with exact identical
        // types.
        template <typename T2> T2  operator = (const T2 &i) {
            ::std::cout << "T2: " << i << ::std::endl;
            T2 &guard = value;
        return value = i;
            throw guard; // Never reached.
        }/**/
        operator T const & () const {
            return value;
        }
};

struct Bar {
    // Using the property<>-template.
    property <bool> alpha;
    property <unsigned int> bravo;
};

int main () {
    Bar bar;
    bar.alpha = true;
    bar.bravo = true; // This line will yield a compile time error
                      // due to the guard template member function.
    ::std::cout << foo.alpha << ", "
                << foo.bravo << ", "
                << bar.alpha << ", "
                << bar.bravo
                << ::std::endl;


    bool bvar = 22;
    int ivar = true;
    //int &newvar = bvar;

    print(bvar);

    ::std::cout << bvar << " and " << ivar << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I think with using of templates the type-checking for references get lost? Am I right?

Comment: The preface is misleading. `int & i = 5;` is equally disallowed. Nothing to do with type promotions.

Comment: @Kerrek SB: I'm completely lost now... Doesn't he said that the second block of code is NOT allowed?

Comment: @K-ballo: the OP implies that the error has to do with types, but that's not the case (it's to do with rvalues, as you know).

Comment: maybe i had a few beers too much (TGIF) but what exactly is the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, type conversions and reference binding rules are the same whether or not there's a template involved. You can bind a temporary (such as the one you need when the referee is a different type to the reference) to a `const` reference, but not to a non-`const` reference.

That is why your second pair of examples fails to compile, and also why the template `operator=` fails to compile in the larger example when the argument type doesn't match the template parameter. In both cases, the code tries to create a temporary through type-conversion and bind it to a non-`const` reference.